# How do I transfer huge amount of data(nearly 10TB) from Oracle DB to Snowflake in hours

Tags: oracle, database-migration, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How do I transfer huge amount of data(nearly 10TB) from Oracle DB to Snowflake in hours? I see some options like Hevo and fivetran which are paid. However, I need the data to be moved fast so that I need not keep the production system down.

Comment: I expect this will be closed as overly broad-- we'd need a lot more detail about the problem to even approach a reasonable design.  It sounds, though, like you're intending to do something like shut the production system down, copy all the data, and then start the production system up again (or move everything to the new environment).  I wouldn't suggest that if you are at all pressed for a downtime window.  It would seem to make much more sense to have a background process that delivers changed data to the new system that can be running while production is still up.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to get data into Snowflake is in 10MB to 100MB chunk files.  Then, you can leverage a big warehouse to COPY INTO all of the chunk files at one time.  I can't speak to how to get the data out of Oracle DB quickly to S3/Azure Blob, though, especially while the system is running its normal workload.

I recommend you look at this document from Snowflake for reference on the Snowflake side:  https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/data-load-considerations-prepare.htm

Answer (score 0):

Is there a network speed issue?
Anyways, the data should be compressed when transferred over the network.

There are three locations involved in the staging:

1. Oracle database,
2. the extraction client,
3. and the cloud storage.

You have two data transfers:

1. between database and client,
2. and between client and cloud storage.

If the Oracle version is 12cR2 or newer, the DB client can compress data when getting it out of the database. The data should then be compressed again and transferred to cloud storage at your Snowflake destination.

The final step is to load the data from cloud storage into Snowflake (within the same data center)...

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you shouldn't need to keep the production database down. You should be able to categorise the data into 
1 - historical data that will not change. You can extract this data at your own leisure, and should not require database to be down.
2 - static data that is fairly stable. You can also extract this data at your leisure

You only need to keep your database fairly stable (not down) when you are extracting the rest of the data. This will require you to build some way to track and validate all your datasets. There is no reason why you couldn't let users continue to read from the database, while you are performing the extract from Oracle.